# What is the current state on Christopher Domas' "killer poke" find?

Tags: x86

On 2017-07-22 Christopher Domas (@xoreaxeaxeax) announced a new "killer poke" that he found on some x86 processor:

https://twitter.com/xoreaxeaxeax/status/888702029744324608 (also cf. https://twitter.com/xoreaxeaxeax/status/891005136041943040).

Neither in the Blackhat presentation (https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Domas-Breaking-The-x86-ISA.pdf) nor in the related paper (https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Domas-Breaking-The-x86-Instruction-Set-wp.pdf) this is answered for responsible disclosure reasons. Since then I heard nothing new about this topic.

So I would like to know whether anybody knows what the current state of this potential killer poke find is or whether anybody has tried out his sandsifter tool (https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/sandsifter) and could reproduce the killer poke on their processor?

Comment: I guess sending a question to the tool creator on github would give better result than asking here.

Comment: ...or ask him on Twitter. I'm not sure why you think any of us would know more than the person who discovered the bug,

Comment: I wrote him an email yesterday, but have not received any answer yet.